# Pure CSS Accordion: Detects "hover" from far below slide

Tags: css, height, accordion

So I've finally managed to get this CSS Accordion mostly working how I want it to. However there's still one strange niggling problem I just can't seem to pin down.

Here's a JS Fiddle with the Accordion: http://jsfiddle.net/RahpC/

Now if you approach the slides from the bottom you can see that they're affected from about 200px away (at least, on my screen).

This same problem is causing the Accordion to have a lot of "white space" below it when put into a page. Originally there were 5 slides and this seems to make me think that somewhere along the line it's still assuming there are 5 slides still.

I've played around with as many of the height settings (%s) and measurements (pixels) as I could before I came to ask here and they just don't seem to affect this "white space" in any way.

Here's the CSS again since code is required with a JSFiddle link, I've removed areas I'm pretty sure arn't affecting anything:

```
/*------------------------------------*\
    MAIN
\*------------------------------------*/
html{
    font-family:Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
    background:url(http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2629908/adaptive/img/css/grid.png) top center repeat-y #fff;
    background:#fff;
    color:#666;
    height:101%;
    font-size-adjust:0.45;
}
h1{
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:2em;
}
h2{
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:1.5em;
}
small{
    color:#ccc;
}
a{
    color:#6b0c36;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:bold;
}
a:hover{
    text-decoration:underline;
}
p{
    margin-bottom:20px;
}

/*------------------------------------*\
    ACCORDION
\*------------------------------------*/
.accordion{
    width:700px;
    overflow:hidden;
    list-style:none;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
}
.accordion li{
    float:left;
    width:20%;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:250px;
    -moz-transition:width 0.2s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition:width 0.2s ease-out;
    -o-transition:width 0.2s ease-out;
    transition:width 0.2s ease-out;
}
.accordion li:first-of-type{
    -moz-border-radius:10px 0 0 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px 0 0 10px;
    -o-border-radius:10px 0 0 10px;
    border-radius:10px 0 0 10px;
}
.accordion li:last-of-type{
    -moz-border-radius:0 10px 10px 0;
    -webkit-border-radius:0 10px 10px 0;
    -o-border-radius:0 10px 10px 0;
    border-radius:0 10px 10px 0;
}
.accordion div{
    padding:10px;
}
.accordion:hover li{
    width:10%;
}
.accordion li:hover{
    width:60%;
}
.slide-01   { background:#139fec; color:white; }            
.slide-02   { background:#118fd4; color:white; }            

/*------------------------------------*\
    VERTICAL
\*------------------------------------*/

#vertical{
    width:700px;
    height:300px;
}
#vertical li{
    height:14%;
    width:100%;
    -moz-transition:height 0.2s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition:height 0.2s ease-out;
    -o-transition:height 0.2s ease-out;
    transition:height 0.2s ease-out;
}
#vertical li:first-of-type{
    -moz-border-radius:10px 10px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px 10px 0 0;
    -o-border-radius:10px 10px 0 0;
    border-radius:10px 10px 0 0;
}
#vertical li:last-of-type{
    -moz-border-radius:0 0 10px 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:0 0 10px 10px;
    -o-border-radius:0 0 10px 10px;
    border-radius:0 0 10px 10px;
}
#vertical:hover li{
    height:10%;
    width:100%;
}
#vertical li:hover{
    height:60%;
    width:100%;
}
```

Any help appreciated as always.

Jon.

Comment: it is because of the #vertical its 300 height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply remove

```
#vertical:hover li{

    height:10%;
}
```

Comment: Yeaaaah! Thanks, that did it :D I don't suppose you could explain -why- that was doing it?

Comment: This hover event looks at the whole accordion whose height is 300px, so that's when it was being triggered, hope this helps.

Comment: Just another quick question in case anyone can help with this, instead of making a new topic. I'm still stuck with the 300px white space below this accordion where the slides ease out. Is there a way to hide this space? Since I'm using multiple accordions on one page, there's this huge gap between them.

Comment: This is because of the height obviously, the actual accordion is filling this space, if you want it to collapse you will have to remove the height value from #vertical and then use a fixed height like 40px, rather than 14% for the #vertical li height, this should give you what you want. This is rather crude but you can see here http://jsfiddle.net/RahpC/17/

Comment: Just to add to the above you should probably merge accordion and fixed as there is a lot of mark-up there to do what you want and if you want to reuse this you need to be using classes rather than ID's.